# How to reset password for logged out user

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using Parse javascript API.  If a user has logged out, I will not have a 'currentUser'.  Therefore, when I try to use the **Parse.User.requestPasswordReset** call, it will not work.  Is there another way to offer users a way to reset their password if they have been logged out?  It seems strange that having a currentUser is required.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't required. You don't say why you think it is, but only an e-mail address is required in order to request a reset (as the result is an e-mail being sent to the user). It's normal to simply have the user type their e-mail address in to trigger the reset logic. Indeed if the user was logged in you would need to be careful about allowing e-mail address editing and then password reset selection...